# Does the Axiom of Substitution Have Limits?

Tags: real-analysis, axioms

According to Terence Tao's book Analysis I, the axiom of substitution is one of the four axioms of equality for *objects* (which are basically eligible set elements). In particular, it says that for any two objects $x$ and $y$ of the same type, if $x$ = $y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$ for all functions and operations $f$, and that furthermore, $P(x)$ and $P(y)$ are logically equivalent propositions (i.e. they imply each other) for all  propositions $P$ whose truth-value depends on $x$ and $y$.

Sometimes, the axiom of substitution makes sense (i.e. is correct), such as when considering *sets* to be the object in question (they are indeed valid objects according to the first set-theory axiom presented in the book), and considering the operation $f(X) = X \cup C$, where $C$ is some arbitrary set. Then indeed, one may verify that if two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal to each other (i.e. $A=B$), then $f(A)=f(B)$ for the operation $f$ defined above.

But there are times when it starts acting up. Still considering sets to be the object in question, let $P(X)$ be the proposition that the elements of $X$ are ordered from least to greatest (this proposition's truth value clearly depends on what the set $X$ is that you "feed" it so to speak). Evidently however, as Tao himself acknowledges, even if two sets $A$ and $B$ were equal to each other, because sets are unordered collections of elements, there are plenty of counterexamples to give that would thoroughly disprove the statement: $P(A)$ iff $P(B)$. So my question then is: does the axiom of substitution have limits to its applicability, and if so, can someone very explicitly clarify what they are? Thanks.

Comment: A set and an ordered set are not the same type of object.

Comment: To me, I think the point is that $P$ is not *well defined* as a proposition on sets, and the substitution principle implicitly requires that what you're substituting into be well defined.

Comment: @DanielSchepler then the question becomes: under what conditions is a proposition P well-defined for some class of objects? After all, the meaning of the adjective "well-defined" when applied to some operation f or proposition P is that it obeys the axiom of substitution for that class of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it is not a problem of the axiom of equality but a problem that your "property" $P$ is not a property.

First of all, since you are "considering the object of sets", you cannot in general talk about "least" or "greatest". For instance, it is meaningless to talk about what element is larger for the set $\{\text{cat, banana}\}$.

Given a finite subset $S$ of integers, "whether the elements of $S$ are ordered from least to greatest" is *not* a property of $S$. This is similar to the scenario that
$$
f(\frac{a}{b})=a+b\qquad a\in\mathbb{Z},\ b\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{1\}.
$$
is *not* a well-defined function on the set of rational numbers. The value of the "function" depends on the concrete representations of the object of rational numbers. For instance, $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{4}$ are the same element in the set of rational numbers, but $1+2\ne 2+4$.

Returning to your case, $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ are two different "representations" (whatever that means) of the same object of sets. But your "property" depends on different "representations" and is thus *not* a property on a finite subset of integers.

Comment: Okay, so to make sure I understand, for any class of objects C (i.e. numbers, vectors, sets, functions, etc.), _some_  properties P(C) are well-defined and so satisfy the axiom of substitution for that class C of objects (e.g. P(vector) : the vector is ∈ $R^2$), but on the other hand there are some "pseudo-properties" for lack of a better word (e.g. P(set) : the first element of the set is the empty set) that are not well-defined and so do not obey the axiom of substitution, and in mathematics we only want to work with the class of possible properties for C that do exhibit substitution.

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral: more or less yes. You may also want to read this page on "predicate": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)

Answer (score 4):

Your statement that $P(X)$ is the proposition that the elements of $X$ are ordered from least to greatest tacitly relies on two assumptions: (1) that $X$ is a sequence of objects and (2) that there is an ordering relation on those objects. When you make those assumptions explicit (as you must if you want to model $P$ in set thoery), then the axiom of substitution holds. You might be interested in the notion of [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency).

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize I had made that assumption, thanks for pointing it out! But even if we assume that the elements of X are for instance only real numbers, two sets (1,2,3) and (2,3,1) are equal even though P[(1,2,3)] is true while P[(2,3,1)] is false, so doesn't that appear to violate the axiom of substitution?

Comment: No. $(1, 2, 3)$ is a sequence and is not the same as $(3, 2, 1)$.

Comment: Well, in the book at least, Tao defines equality of sets to be as follows: two sets A and B are equal (A=B) iff: (x∈A iff x∈B), so if you accept this definition, then indeed the two sets {1,2,3} and {3,2,1} are supposedly equal, since every element of one is an element of the other. How then does one explain the axiom of substitution not being applicable for that property P(X): the elements of X are ordered L to G?

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral: Did you read what Rob said? He said very clearly that $(1,2,3)$ is a **sequence**, not a **set**. Obviously different permutations of a sequence are different, but $\{1,2,3\}$ is **the same set** as $\{3,2,1\}$, just as $1+2$ is the **same object** as $3$.

Comment: In case it is not clear, a set is **never** ordered. That is the whole point of the very notion of "set"; a set simply tells you whether an object is a member of it or not; there is no internal structure or order or anything.

Comment: Of course I understand that sets are not ordered (by definition), but then to me at least this also implies that one has to be very careful when just blindly applying the axiom of substitution to any operation/proposition on any arbitrary class of objects. It seems then that the axiom of substitution is not just something one can assume to hold for any run-of-the-mill operation/proposition on a class of objects (such as making references to the ordering of set elements), but must be CHECKED TO HOLD in order for it to be a well-defined operation/proposition and keep mathematics intact.

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral: I think you need to come up with a more specific example to explain your concerns. If $x = y$, then $x$ really is equal to, i.e., identical with $y$, so anything that holds of $x$ also holds of $y$. On any standard mathematical reading of your question, there is nothing nuanced about this and maths remains intact.

Comment: @RobArthan It's okay now, I think I have it all figured out: humans make up/define various mathematical objects, such as sets, functions, matrices, etc. for whatever purposes, and they get to define what it means for two objects $x$ and $y$ of the same type (e.g. both $x$ and $y$ are sets, or both $x$ and $y$ are vectors, etc.) to be EQUAL, but once this is defined, it is immediately necessary to check that this definition of equality for that class of objects satisfies the symmetric and transitive axioms of equality (which one can think of as basic requirements to be fulfilled).

Comment: But humans do not just want to make up/define all these various sorts of mathematical objects and leave it at that. We also would like to define operations on various objects (i.e. transposing a matrix, intersecting two sets) as well as make Boolean statements about these objects (i.e. vector $v$ is ∈ $R^3$, $f$ is a bijection), and it is here that the axiom of substitution comes into play (again, think of it as a basic requirement to fulfill). Go ahead and define any operation or make any statement on some class of objects as your imagination fancies...

Comment: But it will only be permissible if the axiom of substitution for that operation or statement is verified to hold true (i.e. take two objects $x$ and $y$ of that class and hypothesize their equality $x=y$. Then deduce that the conclusion $f(x)=f(y)$ or the proposition $P(x)$ iff $P(y)$ is true from that hypothesis for whatever operation $f$ or proposition $P$ you came up with). If you can do this successfully, then that operation is WELL-DEFINED, and can be safely accepted into the "bosom of mathematics" if you will.